# Index notation for Gateaux derivative of matrix function confined to subspace of traceless, symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, notation, matrix-calculus, index-notation, gateaux-derivative

Suppose I have a function $\Lambda: S^\text{tr} \to S^\text{tr}$ where $S^\text{tr} = \{Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \: |\: Q = Q^T \: \text{and} \: \text{tr}(Q) = 0\}$ is the space of traceless, symmetric matrices.
I would like to take a [Gateaux derivative](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Gateaux_derivative) in the direction of $\delta Q$:
\begin{equation}
    d\Lambda(Q;\delta Q) = \left.\frac{d}{d\tau} \Lambda(Q + \tau \, \delta Q)\right|_{\tau = 0}
\end{equation}
It would be useful to write down $d\Lambda(Q; \delta Q)$ in index notation.
For an example of what I mean, if it were that $\Lambda: \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, we may write this explicitly as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \left.\frac{d}{d\tau} \Lambda_{ij} \left(Q_{kl} + \tau \, \delta Q_{kl}\right) \right|_{\tau = 0}
    &= \frac{d}{d \tau} \left[\Lambda_{ij} \left(Q\right) + \tau \left.\frac{\partial \Lambda_{ij}}{\partial Q_{kl}}\right|_Q \delta Q_{kl} + \mathcal{O}\left(\tau^2\right) \right] \\
    &= \left.\frac{\partial \Lambda_{ij}}{\partial Q_{kl}}\right|_Q \delta Q_{kl}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where here $\Lambda$ is assumed smooth around $Q$.
My issue is that, when considered explicitly in the subspace $S^\text{tr}$, this appears to be nonsensical.
That is, for $n = 3$ we may identify elements of $S^\text{tr}$ with elements of $\mathbb{R}^5$ as:
\begin{equation}
    Q
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    Q_1 &Q_2 &Q_3 \\
    Q_2 &Q_4 &Q_5 \\
    Q_3 &Q_5 &-(Q_1 + Q_4)
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
with $Q_i$ entries in an element in $\mathbb{R}^5$.
Then we may almost calculate $\partial \Lambda_{ij} / \partial Q_{kl}$ with this mapping, except that $\partial \Lambda_{ij} / \partial Q_{33}$ does not make sense as (to my knowledge) there's not a reasonable notion of differentiating by a sum.

Alternatively, is it valid to understand $\Lambda: \mathbb{R}^5 \to S^\text{tr}$ and notate as:
\begin{equation}
     d\Lambda(Q; \delta Q) = \frac{\partial \Lambda_{ij}}{\partial Q_k} \delta Q_k
\end{equation}
with $k$ indexing entries in $\mathbb{R}^5$?
The purpose of taking the Gateaux derivative is to set up a Newton-Rhapson iteration scheme, for context.

Comment: $\Lambda: \mathbb{R}^5 \to S^\text{tr}\,$ seems like a viable approach. Going further, I would setup the Newton method to solve for the optimal $\mathbb{R}^5$ vector instead of the optimal $Q$ matrix.